# Why does the server chassis backplane have multiple SFF8087 connectors?

Tags: hardware, hardware-raid, sas

On the backplane, there are 5x SFF8087 connectors on a 20x SATA disk setup. Why are there 5x connectors? Do all 5x need to be connected to the motherboard via a SAS Controller, or only one? And does it matter how many ports the SAS Controller has? i.e. if there are 5x SFF8087 ports, does that mean this should be coupled with a 5 Port SAS Controller?

Feeling confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each SFF-8087 port on the backplane provides data for up to *four* of your 20 disks. So five ports are necessary to provide a data connection for all 20 disks.

You connect the ports on the backplane to the ports on your SAS controller, based on the form factor of the respective ports.

Now here's where things get really fun. If your SAS controller doesn't have enough ports, then you may need a SAS expander to sit between them. And in that case the SAS controller has to be compatible with SAS expanders.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is starting to clear things up. This does raise a few more questions though, you mention the 'Form Factor' - is this essentially the number of Ports the SAS Controller has then? When I look at this piece of hardware, there are often only say 2 physical ports on an 8 Port SAS Controller, is that because they require the 1--> 4 splitter cables? And finally - how would one know if a SAS Controller is compatible with a SAS Expander? What would I look for?

Comment: Well, you haven't said what hardware you have. But... "Form factor" means physical shape. SFF-8087 is a different form factor to SFF-8482, etc. You know the number of ports a controller has by looking at it or reading its specifications. A controller with two ports would support 8 drives. (Or possibly more with an expander.) And whether a SAS controller supports SAS expanders is something that's in its specifications.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that has cleared things up. Currently I've got a Silverstone RM420 and a motherboard - and I was wondering how the two bit connect together, which appears to be what I now need is a SAS Controller that can handle 5x Ports, which will likely be a 2x physical ports on the SAS Controller with the 1 --> 4 splitter cables, which should do the job by the sounds of things. The SAS expanders don't sound like something I'd need on this setup, but I'll take a look into those, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelCropper I'm not sure if your calculations on the SAS controller are correct. You would need a SAS controller with five SF-8087 ports. 5x4=20. Something like a MegaRAID 9280-24i4e or a ROCKETRAID 2760A

Comment: Ah yes I see. Looking closer at those splitter cables I was thinking about, it looks like they only support SAS --> SATA and since the SAS Controller has SAS Connectors and the Server Chassis Backplane has SAS Connectors, then it would be 5x SAS --> SAS cables that I'd need - and hence, a SAS Controller that has at least 5x physical SAS connectors on the board.